# Hybrid Android Phonegap app anaytics with Piwik

Tags: android, cordova, analytics, hybrid-mobile-app, matomo

Tracking app usage and events for Android hybrid apps created in Phonegap is an easy affair if one uses Google Analytics.  I implemented my own solution using [this Cordova plugin](https://github.com/cmackay/google-analytics-plugin).  I had expected that implementing Piwik analytics would be just as easy.  I started off with [this plugin](https://github.com/kriserickson/cordova-piwik-plugin) and then followed the instructions to write a little test app. I used the phonegap `jquery-mobile-starter` template whose `app.js` I modified along the following lines

```
$(document).on("deviceready", function() 
{
 deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
 alert('piwik track');
 piwik.startTracker('https://example.com/piwik/piwik.php','siteID'); 
 alert('Device Ready');
});

$(document).on("mobileinit", function () 
{
 jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
 window.onerror = whenError;
 $(document).on('pagecontainershow',pgcShow);
});

function pgcShow()
{
 alert('Page Container now SHOWING!!');
 $('#btn').click(doClick);
}

function doClick()
{
 alert('Click Me');
 piwik.trackEvent('click','I was clicked');
}

function whenError(e,u,l)
{
 alert(e); 
}
```

**Explanations**

- I have attempted to put in enough error handling to be sure that the failure of Piwik analytics is not down to something else in my test code.
- In the PageContainerShow event I hook up the click event for a button on my index.html page to send back a `trackEvent` message back to my Piwik API which is at `https://mypiwikserver.com/piwik/piwik.php'
- `siteID` is the ID of the *"website"* that I created for the purpose picked up from the **All Websites** list on my Piwik Admin console.
- For good measure I have modified the Phonegap `config.xml` file

  access origin="*"
  access origin="https://mypiwikserver.com"

Having done all of this I built the app, installed it on my Android phone, opened it and then went to my Piwik web console expecting to see an event logged in **Actions:Events**. However, I find it stays stubbornly blank.  I have noted no error messages and all of my various `alerts` turn up as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

@DroidOS,
I am going to assume you have a `white-list` issue. I cannot confirm this, but I have read (perhaps in the white-list docs), the some accommodation is made for *some* google websites.

This quick answer may get you a quick fix.

### The fix to many common *white-list* problems

The alternative is this quick fix – but know that this *quick fix* removes all needs for `white-list`. This creates a [security issue](http://www.androidauthority.com/google-webview-security-582363/) which you may not want to by pass.

**QUICK FIX** Add this to your `config.xml` for **PHONEGAP BUILD ONLY**
`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />`

The long answer is as such:

From [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) you have hit:

- #6 **Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**
- #7 **Not setting "version" for you plugins**
- #10 **Not adding the new "white-list" and "white-list plugin" parameters in config.xml.**

For #6 & #7

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading errors.
>
> Luckily for all of us, Holly Schinsky has written a nice blog post to explain it all:
>
> *Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
> http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

For #10

> This relatively * NEW * requirement means – to access ANY website or resources on the web, you MUST use the whitelist and the whitelist plugin. This requirement goes into affect, if you are using cordova-android@4.0.0 or better; including cli-5.1.1 and cli-5.2.0. If however, your version is before 4.0.0, let's say 3.5.0 or 3.7.0, then you will *not* have to add the *white-list* requirement.
>
> To be clear, the "whitelist" has been around for a bit, but the plugin and requirement is very new. As you would expect, when the "whitelist" was added, the defacto open-access feature was deprecated. Or said another way, the defacto open-access feature was planned and scheduled to be eliminated. This change marks a step in removal of the open-access feature.
>
> In addition, the Content Security Policy (CSP) has caught numerous developers - because it was soooo poorly publicized. **Depending on your use and the version of Phonegap you are using, the CSP needs to go in every single HTML page you used, just like you have to wait for 'deviceready'. However, there are cases where it is not needed at all. The documentation is confusing for some, please read it carefully.** The documentation is buried in the bottom of many of the latest documentation pages.
>
> Lastly, Raymond Camden in his blog points to a [LARGE change in policy starting with Cordova 5](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/05/25/important-information-about-cordova-5)

**Related Links**

> Phonegap Build Forum: [Notes for upgrading to cli-5.1.1 on PGB](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/notes-for-upgrading-to-cli-5-1-1-on-pgb) and now required Whitelist
>
> - [Cordova Whitelist Guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist)
> - [Phonegap Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)
> - [Phonegap Build Whitelist Guide](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements)